# Counting how many times each number was typed

Tags: java

Im trying to count how many times each number between 0 to 9 was typed in  a loop, when press -1 it will stop the loop, I made it work with the long term, Also I would have to print which of the numbers was typed the most.
For now I only have the couting code:

```
int pickedNum,counter_0=0,counter_1=0,counter_2=0,counter_3=0,counter_4=0,counter_5=0,counter_6=0,counter_7=0,counter_8=0,counter_9=0;
do{
    System.out.println("Please enter a numbr between 0-9 , -1 to exit:");
    pickedNum=s.nextInt();
    if(pickedNum==0){
        counter_0++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==1){
        counter_1++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==2){
        counter_2++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==3){
        counter_3++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==4){
        counter_4++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==5){
        counter_5++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==6){
        counter_6++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==7){
        counter_7++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==8){
        counter_8++;
    }
    if(pickedNum==9){
        counter_9++;
    }
}
while(pickedNum != -1);
System.out.printf("The number 0 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 1 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 2 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 3 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 4 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 5 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 6 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 7 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 8 appears: %d \n"
        + "The number 9 appears: %d \n", 
        counter_0,counter_1,counter_2,
        counter_3,counter_4,counter_5,
        counter_6,counter_7,counter_8,counter_9);
```

as you can see, It works fine, But I know there is a way better option to do this thing.
And as I mentioned, I also need to print the largest number counts(which number was type the most), and It will take a long way to reach that with my way of programming this.
I would like to get any tip or notes to improve this to work easier and faster.
Any notes would be appriciated.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention to use only basics, and not advanced methods, array and loops are fine.

Comment: Store entries in a `Map`.

Comment: I edit my post,Forgot to mention that I need to use only basic methods and not advanced one, Arrays and loops are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you can have more than one number that was typed the most, take a look at this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int pickedNum, highestCounter = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count[] = new int[10];

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a numbr between 0-9 , -1 to exit:");
        pickedNum = s.nextInt();
        if (pickedNum != -1) {
            count[pickedNum]++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    int index1 = 0;
    for (int i : count) {
        System.out.println("The number " + index1 + " appears : " + i);
        index1++;
    }

    // Finding the number was typed the most
    for (int counter : count) {
        if (counter > highestCounter) {
            highestCounter = counter;
        }
    }

    // In case if you have more than one number that was typed the most
    Integer[] indexes = new Integer[10];
    int index2 = 0;
    for (int counter : count) {
        if (highestCounter == counter) {
            indexes[index2] = index2;
        }
        index2++;
    }

    System.out.print("The number(s) was typed the most is/are : ");
    for (Integer i : indexes) {
        if (i != null) {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }

    }
}
```

And the output :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
int count[] = new int[10];
do{
    counter[pickedNum]++;
} while(pickedNum != -1);
```

And then use counter[0], counter[1] etc in your print statement.